# How can I display my Twilio number for inbound calls

Tags: twilio

I want to display my Twilio line on my caller ID when I receive calls through this line, like Google Voice does.  Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

When you write the TwiML to place a call to a number, you can change the `callerId` attribute in the `<Dial>` TwiML tag. [See the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id). The caller ID number has to be one you have verified with Twilio beforehand. You can verify numbers on your account portal [here](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified).

Here is an example of the TwiML you would need to write to change the caller ID:

```
<Response>
    <Dial callerId='+111111111111'>
        <Number>+122222222222</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The number +111111111111 should be replaced with the callerId you want to appear on the phone you are ringing. I hope that helps!