# Is there a way to display Twilio number in Caller ID without hard-coding it?

Tags: twilio

I have a question similar to this one:
[How can I display my Twilio number for inbound calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297898/how-can-i-display-my-twilio-number-for-inbound-calls)

However, I now have two separate Twilio numbers that both point to the same URL, so hard-coding the number as Caller ID is no longer an option. Is there a method I can use to get which Twilio number was called? I know that PhoneNumber gets the caller's number, so I need a way to distinguish which of my two numbers are calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

When Twilio makes its HTTP request to your application letting you know that someone has called your Twilio number, we pass along [a bunch of form-encoded parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request), including which Twilio phone number the person called.  Your web platform should have a way to grab those parameters fro mthe incoming request.  For example in PHP it looks like this:

```
$from = $_REQUEST['To'];
```

In .NET, there are a number of ways to do it, but here is one:

```
Request.Form["To"]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was hoping to catch a Twilio evangelist!

Thanks for the answer, a simple answer for a simple question. I was actually looking for the 'To' number. Now that I've implemented that it's working like a charm.